# Why does execvp only work for the first command entered in my shell?

Tags: c++, c, shell, exec

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char input[100];
#define DELIMITERS " \t\n"
char * tokens[100];
int numTokens = 0;
int i = 0;
int n = 0;
char * cmd;

// function prototype
void nonBuiltin(char * inputs[]);
void handlePipe(char * cmds[]);

// this breaks the input into tokens and returns them
char * tokenize(char input[100])
{
  n = 0;
  // grabs input and separates by delimiters until the char is null
  for(cmd = strtok(input, DELIMITERS); cmd; cmd = strtok(NULL, DELIMITERS))
    {
      if(n >= 100)
       {
         break;
       }
      tokens[n++] = cmd;
      numTokens++;
    } 

    for(size_t i = 0; i != n; i++)
      {
        printf("Tokens %zu is %s\n", i, tokens[i]);
      }
    return * tokens;
}

// handles the commands you enter
// checks if builtin or non builtin command
// if builtin, execute command
// else, send command to nonbuiltin function
void handleCommands(char * inputs)
{
  // changes directory
  if(strcmp(tokens[0], "cd") == 0)
    {
      int change = chdir(tokens[1]);
      if(change == 0)
        {
          chdir(tokens[1]);
        }
      else
        {
          perror("Cannot find path specified...\n");
        }
    }
  // prints working directory
  else if(strcmp(tokens[0], "pwd") == 0)
    {
      printf("Your current working directory is: %s\n", getenv("PWD"));
    }
  // implements set command
  else if(strcmp(tokens[0], "set") == 0)
    {
      // do this
    }
  // exits program
  else if(strcmp(tokens[0], "exit") == 0)
    {
      printf("Now exiting...\n");
      exit(3);
    }
  // input contains a nonbuiltin command
  // sends input to nonbuiltin function
  else
    {
      printf("Your command is a nonbuilt-in command\n");
      nonBuiltin(tokens);
    }
}

void nonBuiltin(char * inputs[])
{
  int fp;
  int status;

  // create a new process
  pid_t pid;
  pid = fork();
  // process creation was unsuccessful
  if(pid < 0)
    {
      perror("Fork unsuccessful...\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
  // child process
  else if(pid == 0)
    {
      // printf("Fork successful...\n");
      if(numTokens >= 3)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < numTokens; i++)
        {
          if(strcmp(tokens[i], "<") == 0)
          {
            tokens[i] = tokens[i+1];
            fp = open(tokens[i], O_RDONLY, 0);
            dup2(fp, 0);
            execvp(tokens[0], tokens);
          }
          else if(strcmp(tokens[i], ">") == 0)
          {
            tokens[i] = tokens[i+1];
            fp = open(tokens[i], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
            dup2(fp, 1);
            close(fp);
            tokens[i]= NULL;
            execvp(tokens[0], tokens);

          }
          else if(strcmp(tokens[i], "|") == 0)
            {
              tokens[i] = tokens[i+1];
              handlePipe(tokens);
            }
        }
    }

      else
      {
       // printf("Nothing special as far as commands go\n");
       execvp(tokens[0], tokens); 


      }
    }
  // wait for child process to end
  else
    {
      waitpid(-1, &status, WUNTRACED);
      printf("the child process has now terminated\n");
     // exit(0);
    }

}


void handlePipe(char * cmds[])
{
    printf("Initiate piping\n");
    // file descriptors
    int fd[2];
    // fd[0] is the read end of pipe
    // fd[1] is the write end of pipe
    pipe(fd);

    if(!fork())
      {
        // first close the write end
        close(1);
        // fd[1] can now take stdout
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        execvp(cmds[0], cmds);

      }
     else
      {
        // close read end
        close(0);
        // fd[1] can now take stdin
        dup(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(cmds[1], cmds);
      }


}

// starts the program and asks the user to enter input
// loops until the user enters 'exit'
int main()
{
  while(1)
    {
      printf("Enter a command...\n");
      fgets(input, 100, stdin);
      handleCommands(tokenize(input));
    }
}
```

> When I run my shell program, I enter in a command, like ls or cat, and
>   the command executes properly. If I run another command after that
>   one, the command will not execute at all. It could even be the same
>   command as the first one I entered, and it will still not run for the
>   second time. No error messages are given. It just doesn't output what
>   the command calls it to output. I'm currently using execvp, and I believe I am passing in the arguments currently, so I'm not sure where to go from here. Could someone give me some input on
>   why this is happening?

Comment: Please share what debugging you have performed (if any) and what you have found out. For example, have you run your program in a debugger and/or added more debug print statements to trace the execution of your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you feel is appropriate (it worked for me in the main loop, although I'll leave the design up to you):

```
numTokens = 0;
```

You aren't resetting the number of tokens which you increment in the tokenize function. Using a global variable makes it easy to miss little things like this.

Comment: Whoa, thank you so much! I never would have thought of that unfortunately.

Comment: I wouldn't have caught it that quickly either, this is why valgrind and gdb are your friends. Valgrind immediately told me you were trying to do an invalid read after one command, and the line of code where this was happening, so I took a closer look at your tokenize function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely look into those debuggers